# Jump quickly to Output File from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, build

From within Visual Studio, is there any way that I can launch Windows Explorer at the location of the binary that an individual project builds?

Xcode 3 lists the built binaries on the left hand side in its equivalent of Solution Explorer. If I right click on one, I have an option to "Reveal in Finder".

There are a number of simple workarounds like say keeping Windows Explorer always open at a particular location, but all of the workarounds I can think of are a bit slow and clunky when it comes to building multiple projects from multiple products and then copying to an install area.

I have 2005, 2008 and 2010 installed, all with Visual Assist.

Thanks.

Comment: Click the Show All Files icon in Solution Explorer so you can see all of the files and folders, not just those that are part of your project.  Then just right-click a folder and click "Open Folder in Windows Explorer".

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. This was almost there, except I failed to mention that the build areas aren't located in the same place as the project files. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and go to "Properties"
Under "Build Events" there is a spot for post-build commands to run.  You can set an option (at the bottom) to always run, or just when the project output is updated by the build.

If you click the "Edit Post-build ..." button, you'll have a way to find some of the variables for your project, such as the directory where the output goes.

To get Explorer to pop up at the location, you can use:
   explorer $(TargetDir)

However, you may be able to do more complex things, such as automating the copy of files to an installation area.

(Tested on Win 7, VS2010)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've learnt something new. I didn't really get what I wanted so have resorted to just creating some scripts that I can quickly run. Thanks anyway.